# Converting Rows value as Column name dynamically and finding total quantity – PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have 3 tables A,B,C. like [image: this]

Need to Show some details on a sql table combining these 3 tables(RESULT).
I need to show the value of date field as column heading dynamically.
Referred this link http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/converting-rows-to-columns-pivot-and-columns-to-rows-unpivot-in-sql-server.html but it was for static values. Is there any way to implement this for dynamic data.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have removed the MySQL tag since you seem to be using SQL Server.

Comment: I'm a beginner on pivots, but if I get you right, you want to **not** specify the `C_date` column values in the query (*in this case 5 values*), because that means the query will not adapt to new values (*e.g. 31-05-2017) unless you update it, right? But, doesn't his article already cover that via `@PivotColumns`? TBH I barely skimmed it but that's what I sensed.

Comment: c_date is a datetime field but i want only the date .ie., 05-03-2017...

Answer (score 0):

THIS SHOULD WORK

```
CREATE TABLE #A (A_ID INT, A_Name Varchar(100))
INSERT INTO #A VALUES (1,'X'),(2,'Y'),(3,'Z');

CREATE TABLE  #B (B_ID INT,A_ID INT, B_Name Varchar(100))
INSERT INTO #B VALUES (10,1,'P'),(11,2,'Q'),(12,1,'R');

CREATE TABLE #C  (B_ID INT,C_DATE DATE, C_QTY INT)
INSERT INTO #C VALUES (10,'2017-01-01',100),(10,'2017-01-02',200),
                       (11,'2017-01-03',250),(11,'2017-01-03',50),(12,'2017-01-07',300);
 ------------- PIVOT AS FOLLOWS                      

DECLARE @Cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(C_DATE) FROM #C 
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE   ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')    

SET @query =  'SELECT* FROM(
                SELECT  
                A.A_Name,
                B.B_Name,
                C.C_DATE,
                C.C_QTY
          FROM #A A
          RIGHT JOIN #B B ON A.A_ID=B.A_ID
          RIGHT JOIN #C C ON B.B_ID=C.B_ID
               ) ABC
PIVOT 
(
SUM(C_QTY) FOR [C_DATE] IN (' + @Cols + ')

) AS PV1';

EXEC sp_executesql @query 

DROP TABLE #A; DROP TABLE #B;DROP TABLE #C
```

Comment: @Shalu, please clarify, the only differences I see against your image are:(1) having `NULL` instead of blank, (2) missing the last column [result] which sums all the dates, (3) the [2017-01-01] column not containing the text (Cdate). Are any of these your concern? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

In relation with the previous solution given by JonWay, in order to add a 'Result' column with the overall quantity for a A_name and B_name we can create a totals view and add it to the main query this way

```
CREATE TABLE A (A_ID INT, A_Name Varchar(100))
INSERT INTO A VALUES (1,'X'),(2,'Y'),(3,'Z');

CREATE TABLE  B (B_ID INT,A_ID INT, B_Name Varchar(100))
INSERT INTO B VALUES (10,1,'P'),(11,2,'Q'),(12,1,'R');

CREATE TABLE C  (B_ID INT,C_DATE DATE, C_QTY INT)
INSERT INTO C VALUES (10,'2017-01-01',100),(10,'2017-01-02',200),
                   (11,'2017-01-03',250),(11,'2017-01-03',50),(12,'2017-01-07',300);

-- Create the view separately after having created the tables
CREATE VIEW R_sum
AS
SELECT A.A_id, B.B_id, SUM(C.C_qty) AS Sum_qty
FROM     A INNER JOIN
                  B ON A.A_id = B.A_id INNER JOIN
                  C ON B.B_id = C.B_id
GROUP BY A.A_id, B.B_id

 ------------- PIVOT AS FOLLOWS                      

DECLARE @Cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(C_DATE) FROM C 
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE   ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')    

SET @query =  'SELECT * FROM(
                SELECT  
                A.A_Name,
                B.B_Name,
                C.C_DATE,
                C.C_QTY,
                R.Sum_qty as Result
          FROM A A
          INNER JOIN B ON A.A_ID=B.A_ID
          RIGHT JOIN C ON B.B_ID=C.B_ID
          RIGHT JOIN R_Sum R ON B.A_ID=R.A_ID AND B.B_ID=R.B_ID
               ) ABC
PIVOT 
(
SUM(C_QTY) FOR [C_DATE] IN (' + @Cols + ')

) AS PV1';

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: shows an error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'."

Comment: How weird, I have tested it and it works. Can you check if tables A, B and C and the view R_sum have been created in your database?

Comment: @Shalu, I can cause that error by running all the code from `CREATE VIEW` to the very end, perhaps that is it? Correct usage is until `GROUP BY` only, then run the rest. In any case, it gives the same output as JonWay's.

Comment: The system requests to execute the "CREATE view" command separately, so I added a comment just above the "CREATE view"  explaining it.

Comment: It works well.Can u help me to group by the result based on A_name